# Making QualifiedDo and ApplicativeDo work together when nesting applicative functors

Tags: haskell, applicative, do-notation

I want to define deeply nested [compositions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) of applicative functors. For example something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont
import Control.Arrow (Kleisli (..))
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.Functor.Compose
import Data.Functor

type Configurator = Kleisli Parser Value
type Allocator = ContT () IO 
type Validator = Either String

someConfigurator :: Configurator Int
someConfigurator = undefined

someAllocator :: Allocator Char
someAllocator = undefined

-- the nested functor composition. left-associated
type Phases = Configurator `Compose` Allocator `Compose` Validator 

data Foo = Foo Int Char

-- I want to streamline writing this, without spamming the Compose constructor 
fooPhases :: Phases Foo
fooPhases = _
```

To streamline the syntax for creating the `fooPhases` value, I though of (ab)using [`QualifiedDo`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/qualified_do.html?highlight=qualifieddo#extension-QualifiedDo):

```
module Bind where
import Data.Functor
import Data.Functor.Compose

(>>=) :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> g b) -> Compose f g b 
(>>=) f k = bindPhase f k

(>>) :: Functor f => f a -> g b -> Compose f g b 
(>>) f g = Compose $ f <&> \_ -> g

fail :: MonadFail m => String -> m a
fail = Prelude.fail

bindPhase :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> g b) -> Compose f g b 
bindPhase f k = Compose (f <&> k)
```

Somewhat to my surprise, it worked:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QualifiedDo #-}
import qualified Bind
fooPhases :: Phases Foo
fooPhases = Bind.do 
    i <- someConfigurator 
    c <- someAllocator 
    pure (Foo i c)
```

Alas, when I add applicative-like functions to the `Bind` module

```
return :: Applicative f => a -> f a
return = Prelude.pure

pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
pure = Prelude.pure

fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap = Prelude.fmap

join :: f (g a) -> Compose f g a
join = Compose

(<*>) :: (Applicative f, Applicative g) => f (a -> b) -> g a -> Compose f g b
(<*>) f g = Compose $ f <&> \z -> Prelude.fmap (z $) g
```

and then enable [`ApplicativeDo`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/applicative_do.html?highlight=applicativedo#extension-ApplicativeDo) in `Main`, I start to get errors like the following:

```
* Couldn't match type: Compose (Kleisli Parser Value) (ContT () IO)
                 with: Kleisli Parser Value
  Expected: Configurator (Compose Allocator Validator Foo)
    Actual: Compose
              (Kleisli Parser Value)
              (ContT () IO)
              (Compose Allocator Validator Foo)
```

Is there a way to use my `Bind.do` when *both* `QualifiedDo` and `ApplicativeDo` are enabled in `Main`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make this easier to reason about, first manually desugar `fooPhases` each way:

```
fooPhasesMonad = 
    someConfigurator Bind.>>= \i ->
    someAllocator Bind.>>= \c ->
    pure (Foo i c)

fooPhasesApplicative = Bind.fmap Foo someConfigurator Bind.<*> someAllocator
```

If you check their types in GHCi, you'll see that `fooPhasesMonad` has the type you want (as expected, since it works), but `fooPhasesApplicative` has type `` (Configurator `Compose` Allocator) Foo ``.

The first problem is that `Bind.fmap f m` isn't equivalent to `m Bind.>>= (pure . f)`. In particular, the latter produces an extra layer of `Compose` but the former does not. When you use `ApplicativeDo`, using the former instead means you end up with just `` (Configurator `Compose` Allocator) `` instead of `` (Configurator `Compose` Allocator `Compose` Validator) ``, which is the cause of your type error. To fix it, replace your definition of `Bind.fmap` with this one:

```
fmap :: (Functor f, Applicative g) => (a -> b) -> f a -> Compose f g b
fmap f k = bindPhase k (Prelude.pure . f)
```

The "monads" of your do-notation fail all of the monad laws, though (even the types of the results can't be right), so some rewrites that you take for granted aren't still valid. In particular, you'll still get an error unless you settle for your types being composed like this instead:

```
type Phases = (Configurator `Compose` Validator) `Compose` Allocator
```